# Alternative for createrange IE8

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8, textarea, highlight

iv searched around but couldn't find any helpful answer , So this is it:

iv got an iframe which will have some rich text inside and beneath it a text area , the thing is iv got a script that will write text inside the iframe and im using javascript to select that text as follows:

```
iframeElement=document.getElementById("iframeEmailBody");
contentDoc=iframeElement.contentDocument;
range=contentDoc.createRange();
range.setStart(contentDoc.body.childNodes[0],0);
range.setEnd(contentDoc.body.childNodes[5],0);
selection=iframeElement.contentWindow.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

this will select the text so then later the script im writing will click on some rich text thing(italic,bold...) and change the text , well the code above is working find but not in IE8 as i get the following Error

> **"Object doesn't support this property or method"**

i would guess it's because the CreateRange function is not supported in IE8 , iv tried looking for an alternative but couldn't find , help is appreciated , Thanks.